# Generate colums w/ Angular Material using an *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, frontend, ngfor

I'm using a tutorial that takes data from the component.

Here I have to insert every column by myself, instead I want to generate them like the example on the bottom of the page.

```
<div>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.firstName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here I wasn't using Material, I generated every column from a string[]:

```
getColumns(): string[] {
  return ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'age'];
}//this is in my service
```

So if I delete or modify a column in my service, it will be removed in the table.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let col of columns" >{{col}}
  </th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
  <td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{user[col]}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
</div>
```

How can I apply the same method in the ng-container, th and td's?

Comment: Your question does not explain your expected output nor the problem you're getting. Please explain more or you can check [How to ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @GigaBite I edited the question, hope it's better now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Like This.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-info">
                                <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>Qty</th>
                                        <th>Amount</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr *ngFor='let kotitems of cartitems'>
                                        <td>{{kotitems.Product}}</td>
                                        <td>{{kotitems.Qty}}</td>
                                        <td>{{kotitems.Amt}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot class="bg-primary text-white">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Total</td>
                                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">{{getSum()}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
```